# Is there a way to increase the odds of making half-inch successful?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I've noticed that I am quite often unsuccessful with half-inch when trying to thieve items from monsters.

Is there items or anything else that I can do to help increase these odds?  Does agility or deftness play into effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes - more deftness.**  One part of the formula for success of Half Inch is the Deftness of the character using it.

You can equip one of the many kinds of gloves which increase deftness.  The Honour Among Thieves accessory is the most effective at increasing the success of Half Inch.

The Ranger job has the highest starting Deftness, and can also earn a few natural Deftness bonuses.